# how to delete images from db using php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to delete images from database using PHP.

I use the following code:

```
$del=$_GET['picid'];
$ins="delete from photos where photo_id='$del'";
$result=mysql_query($ins);
```

but the images are deleted only in MySQL table not in server

I need to delete images from both MySQL table and server

Comment: SQL injection is possible with your current code.

Comment: MySQL table is not in a database?

Comment: u mean blob type field in db?

Answer (score 2):

Mysql DB > Table > Fields

Your question doesn't really make sense. If what you are trying to do is delete the file from the file system (i.e. off the disk), then you will want to use [unlink](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php).

Answer (score 1):

To remove an image from the server, use [`unlink()`](http://php.net/unlink) :

```
unlink("images/myImage.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

if you mean to delete the file from the server, then you have to use `unlink($image_path);` function in PHP in order to delete the file.